# How to get consistent normals on a curved mesh

Tags: faces, normals

I'm trying to create a curved wall using a simple deform. I expected the normals to consistently point perpendicular to each face, but instead, there is a sudden change at different points causing the the angle between some faces to be harsh and noticeable. How do I fix this and how do I avoid it in the first place? Does it have anything to do with the placement and/or subsequent repositioning of the object I used to deform the cube around?

[image: Curved Wall]

[image: Curved Wall Geometry]

[image: Faces]

[image: Top]

Comment: Don't know how to avoid it happening, but you can recalculate normals in Edit Mode with Shift+n. You can press Alt+n instead to get a menu with even more options.

Comment: Thanks. I've experimented with all of the options in the Edit Mode Normals sub-menu, but they either do nothing or don't affect the normals in a way that is any better, just different but equally undesirable.

Comment: I must confess to not knowing how the vast majority of those settings work. The only one I use regulary is Shift+n to essentially recalculate all the normals of selected geometry to the object's outside.